# How to change SourceGear Vault server address in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sourcegear-vault

I have a project that I have only been working on locally and I have setup the Source Gear Vault to access the server with a local url. I am now going to be working on this project at home and need to change the server address to use a different url to access the server remotely. I know how to do this in the stand alone client, but can't find a way to do it inside Visual Studio.

Comment: You have a couple of choices.  You can spend more $$$ and purchase SourceOffSite:  http://www.sourcegear.com/sos/.  Or you can do something *really* smart like *dump* Visual Source Safe, and get a *real* version control system like SVN or Git:  http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/axfuf/why_the_hatred_for_visual_sourcesafe_is_it_really/  IMHO..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're dealing with is the bindings that go inside your .sln and project files and point to your source control product.  If you unbind your solution and rebind it to the new server location, you should be able to work with a different server URL.

More details about binding can be found in this KB article on the SourceGear website: http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=18956.

In fact, the specific entry from that article that will be useful is Rebinding to a Different Server: http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=18956&p=68403#p68403.

Feel free to call (217) 356-0105 x700, or fling an email to support @sourcegear.com.